# Teach an AI to catch a ball?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, physics

I have a game that effectively has two paddles in it, and I've got it working set up so that either the players or an AI can control either paddle. However, I'm trying to figure out how to get my AI to actually smoothly run after the ball and catch it, instead of simply brute-forcing it with a basic "Direction of Ball" = Opposite direction AI moves.

In order to do so, I'm trying to write some code that will allow the AI to predict where it will land, when the ball is in it's court or going to be. It's not going that well. This is a diagram of what I want to achieve:

[image: Parabolic arc of ball and prediction points]

So, I've been studying Unity3D and came up with this:

```
Vector3 BallMinder = BallPosition.gameObject.rigidbody.velocity;
float BallX = BallMinder.x;
float BallY = BallMinder.y * Time.deltaTime;
float GroundHitPointX = (BallY + BallX);

Vector3 BallImpactPoint = new Vector3 (GroundHitPointX, 0, 0);
Debug.Log (BallImpactPoint);
Debug.DrawRay (BallImpactPoint, Vector3.up, Color.green);
```

However, I feel like I've oversimplified it or forgotten something. My calculations are way off, and the ray isn't showing up where it should, if it does at all. What have I gotten wrong?

Comment: I think you can do it pretty simply. You take the X position of the ball and make the Computer padle move to that position at a his max speed. For the solution that the computer padle should wait at where the ball will touch down you will need to calculate the drop down spot (as you did) but apperently its the wrong calculation heh :)

Comment: That's what I was doing before, and it never quite felt human - I want the AI to at least act like it's another player and try to catch the ball instead of moving towards it and getting maybe 50% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

essentialy you apply gravity to the ball at every step to make it seem natural something like this:

ball is at your position ready to be trown

```
ball.x = 20;
ball.y = 10;
xVelocity = 0; 
yVelocity = 0;
gravity = 0.1;
```

you trow the ball
When you trow the ball you set xVelocity to a constant lets say 1 and yVelocity to 5. So:

```
xVelocity = 1;
yVelocity = 5;
ball.x+=xVelocity;
ball.y+=yVelocity; //to start the ball moving
```

Now in the gameloop you calculate the ball position like this:

```
tick
{
    if(ball.y > 10)  //if the ball is off the ground (i asume 10 is ground) 
    {
        ball.x+=xVelocity;
        ball.y+=yVelocity;
        yVelocity-=gravity;
    }
}
```

with this the ball should fly in a perfect arc now to calculate the landing zone you can simply do the same thing again with dummy numbers

```
while(dummyBall.y > 10)
{
    dummyBall.x+=xVelocity;
    dummyBall.y+=yVelocity;
    yVelocity-=gravity;
}
landingPosX = dummyBall.x;
```

You will probably need to tweak the numbers but if i remember everything correctly it should work something like this. Hope it make sense

Comment: So I was close but no cigar. The ball already moves on it's own with physics and gravity, but I was trying to figure out how to apply the gravity to the landing zone calculation. I'll try this when I can.

Comment: It was a little hard to choose an answer with so many good ones. I was half way there, and used this to help fix the rest of it. Or at least part of it. It deserves the approval mark.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be simplified by assuming that gravity is downward, and the floor is at `Y=0`. It could be expanded using vector math for arbitrary floorlines and gravity directions, but for your purposes you should be fine using the two aforementioned assumptions. I'm also assuming for this explanation that `BallPosition` is a `Transform` object, but the math would be the same if it weren't. I'm also assuming no air friction on the ball, which would make the math a fair bit more complicated.

Essentially, you need to calculate the time until the ball hits the ground and then extrapolate the ball's X-position at that time.

The classic formula dictating the motion of an accelerating object is `d = vt + at^2 / 2`, where `v` is the current velocity, `a` is the acceleration, and `t` is the amount of time that has passed. To figure out the time of impact, we simply solve for `t`.

[image: d = vt + at^2/2 solve for t]

To figure out when the ball will hit the ground you'll want to set `d = BallPosition.position.y * -1`, `a = Physics.gravity.y`, and `v = BallPosition.rigidbody.velocity.y`. This will give us the number of seconds until impact.

Since gravity is assumed to be entirely downward and no other forces are acting on the ball, we can know that the X-position of the ball at impact time is `BallPosition.position.x + BallPosition.rigidbody.velocity.x * impactTime`. This would be the X-position your computer player should move towards.

...The formula should work any time the gravity is entirely downward, even if the ball is on the upward portion of its trajectory or moving away from your computer player. You'll probably want to come up with some strategy for what the computer should do while waiting for the human to hit the ball and set the ball's new trajectory, since you probably don't want the computer to try to run towards the human's side of the net. Depending on how your players are able to hit the ball, you might be able to predict the new velocity the ball would have after the human hits it, and then feed that data to this formula.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the [**Kinematics**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics) equations.

[image]

These equations perfectly describe a projectile in motion. Therefore, you can use them to predict where and with what components the ball will land.

Here is a graph to help you understand.

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that the physics engine of the game is likely not as robust as the real world, and this may not in fact be a suitable predictor of where the object will actually end up.

Comment: @Servy I figured that OP would handle his own Physics, such as adding Force to the ball, and then controlling the acceleration himself. I tend to rely on my Physics not what Unity3d gives me; I only use it for graphics rendering. However, you do make an excellent point, if OP is heavily relying on the engine's Physics.